# Splitting the data in Python

Tags: python, list

I am not getting how to split string.

```
a = ['hostname1-Link1-2582',
'hostname2_1/3/10',
'hostname100',
'hostanme250_1']
```

Above is my data. I want to capture if list item contains continuous numeric format after _ or -.

In this case I want to capture 2582 from hostname1-Link1-2582 this and 1 from hostanme250_1 this.

where second list item and 3rd list item doesn't not have this format so i want to ignore those.

so i expect output should be like

output = [2581,NA,NA,1]

could anyone please help me to split these data and store it into list.

I have tried like below:

```
 for i in a:
   i.split('-')[2]
```

Comment: You need to assign the result of `i.split('-')[2]` to a variable and do something with it.

Answer (score 2):

This is one approach using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re
a = ['hostname1-Link1-2582',
'hostname2_1/3/10',
'hostname100',
'hostanme250_1']

result = []
for i in a:
    m = re.search(r"(_|\-)(\d+)$", i)
    if m:
        result.append(m.group(2))
    else:
        result.append("NA")
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['2582', 'NA', 'NA', '1']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that does not use regular expressions.

```
output = list()

for elem in a:
    elem = elem.replace('_', '-')
    split = elem.split('-')
    last_word = split[-1]

    if last_word.isdigit():
        output.append(last_word)
    else:
        output.append('NA')
```

Output:

```
['2582', 'NA', 'NA', '1']
```